# RSA - What to do when message is greater than N

Tags: rsa

Exmple: $e=3, n=33$ and $d =7$ and Message is $64$.

Answer (score 2):

“Not use (only) RSA.”

While RSA can be used to transport a message smaller than N (well, actually smaller than a different N that fits inside the padding aperture), the usual solution is to send data like

```
RSA(aesKey) || IV/nonce || AES(aesKey, message)
```

in the hybrid cryptosystem model.

When dealing with toy implementations of RSA (with 7-bit keys) you could have the message be a 6-bit encryption key, e.g. a Caesar cipher shift index.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* write $E_3(64)=64^3\equiv(-2)^3\equiv(31)^3\pmod{33}$ to get the values on desired range.

But this is a bad habit in terms of message encryption (and decryption). Generally the message space should be smaller than $\#\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ ( $32$ in this case ). Otherwise the encryption $E_e(x):\mathcal{P}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$  is not bijective: symbols $64$ and $31$ would produce the same ciphertexts and recovering the plaintext would be difficult (unless some specific protocol is used).

Answer (score 1):

RSA works over $\mathbb{Z}_n$, therefore, you cannot encrypt and decrypt more than $n$ values.

But you can choose the representatives of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to include other values instead of the classic $\{0, 1, ..., n-1\}$.

For example, if you know that you will never encrypt values smaller than $n/2$, then you can represent $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\{n/2, n/2+1, ..., n+n/2\}$, so that you can work some values bigger than $n$.

If you still want to encrypt values from $0$ to $n-1$ and encrypt those additional values bigger than $n$, then there is little to do.

One option is to write the message in base $n$ and encrypt each word, but of course, you get then a vector of ciphertexts instead of a single ciphertext.

For example, $64$ is $(1, 31)$ in base $33$, then you can encrypt $2$ and $1$, which are in the original range $\{0, ..., n-1\}$.