# How Paillier cryptosystem can be used practically to encrypt and decrypt big messages "m"?

Tags: encryption, public-key, paillier

I want to use the Paillier cryptosystem for encryption and decryption purposes in my research work. But i haven't found a way to encrypt big input messages;
As i want to encrypt the **message** i,e **m** :

```
m = 0xa56f89d6aa234776b22347293429ff074928ab3749cc2837c492b874ebfaba78364ba0912efe862f628347982478b
```

**Key Gen:**

```
p =887, q = 907 , n =804509 ,n² = 647234731081;
g = n+1 = 804510;
λ = LCM(p-1,q-1) = 401358;
μ = L(g^λ mod n²)^(-1) mod n = 637146
```

**Encryption:**

```
Let random r = 1987
 c = ((g^m) * (r^n)) (mod n^2)
```

How can calculate `g^m` for such big input `m`?

If encrypted, then how can decryption work for big messages i,e `m`?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71960/rsa-what-to-do-when-message-is-greater-than-n).

Comment: The entire reason Pallier is interesting is because of the partial homomorphic properties; that is, given $E(a)$ and $E(b)$, someone with only the public key can compute $E(a + b \bmod n)$.  What are your homomorphic goals if $a > n$?  If "none at all", then standard hybrid crypto (use Pallier to encrypt a symmetric key, and then use the symmetric key to encrypt the actual message) is your answer.

Comment: No i don't want to use Pallier to encrypt only symmetric key, i want to encrypt some big data(hexadecimal values)

Comment: But what is your goal?  What problem are you trying to solve?  "Using Pallier to encrypt a large amount of data" is a solution, not a goal.

Comment: @poncho here i define my goal https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/73023/can-paillier-rsa-or-any-other-schemes-be-used-for-universal-re-encryption-like

Answer (score 2):

The Paillier cryptosystem allows to encrypt integers modulo $n$. Therefore, if $m$ is bigger than $n$, encrypting it will lose most of the message - only $m \bmod n$ is retrieved through decryption.

To encrypt a message bigger than $n$, you must break it into blocks, which you encrypt separately. You can for example write $m$ in base $n$, as $m = \sum_i m_i n^{i}$, and encrypt the $m_i$'s separately with Paillier.

Also, regarding how to calculate $g^m \bmod n^2$: note that $g = n+1$, hence

$g^m = (1+n)^m = 1 + n\cdot m \bmod n^2$

(if you develop $(1+n)^m$, you get $1 + nm + n^2\cdot \mathsf{something}$, and the $\mathsf{something}$ disappears modulo $n^2$).

Comment: Is there material/ paper which can help me to implement this

Comment: There are probably plenty of resources online about implementations of the Paillier cryptosystem in all major languages. I do not know much about that, since I never implemented it myself.

Comment: This does not give an IND-CCA2/NM-CCA2 public-key encryption scheme as one usually expects from the term ‘public-key encryption’.